# Restkit. How to post NSDictionary inside NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, restkit

I want to reach the following result in request.body
CarwashForm[workmode][1][status]=1

where [1] is id of object

```
@interface  WorktimeForm : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *isset;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *weekday;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *status;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *work_from;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *work_to;
@end;

@interface CarwashForm : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *latitude;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *longitude;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray<NSString*> *files;
@property NSDictionary *workmode;
@end
```

The mapping code in screenshot http://joxi.ru/4AkOO4kiMvQ4aA . I use the different cases (for array, dictionary, nsset ) but cannot the get suitable result

`NSDictionary *workmode` is list of object with key ID.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help this:

```
  [delegate startProgress];
    self.manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    NSMutableDictionary *dtPost = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [dtPost setObject:carwash.name forKey:@"CarwashForm[name]"];
    [dtPost setObject:carwash.address forKey:@"CarwashForm[address]"];
    [dtPost setObject:carwash.latitude forKey:@"CarwashForm[latitude]"];
    [dtPost setObject:carwash.longitude forKey:@"CarwashForm[longitude]"];

    for (WorktimeForm* wt in carwash.workmode){
        [dtPost setObject:wt.status forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CarwashForm[workmode][%@][isset]",wt.weekday]];
        [dtPost setObject:wt.status forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CarwashForm[workmode][%@][status]",wt.weekday]];
        [dtPost setObject:wt.work_from forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CarwashForm[workmode][%@][work_from]",wt.weekday]];
        [dtPost setObject:wt.work_to forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CarwashForm[workmode][%@][work_to]",wt.weekday]];
    }

    [self.manager postObject:dtPost path:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"carwash/%d",[id_wash intValue]] parameters:dtPost success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
        NSLog(@"%@",@"OK saveCarwash");
        [delegate success:200 toPack:mappingResult toMsg:@"success"];
        [delegate stopProgress];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"ERROR saveCarwash");
        [delegate stopProgress];
        [delegate fail:500 toMsg:[error localizedFailureReason]];
    }];
```